# Parsing diferent bs4.element.Tag with beautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, url, beautifulsoup

I want to parse the table in this url and export it as a csv:

http://www.bde.es/webbde/es/estadis/fi/ifs_es.html

if i do this:

```
sauce = urlopen(url_bank).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')
```

and then this:

```
resto = soup.find_all('td')
lista_text = []
for elements in resto:
    lista_text = lista_text + [elements.string]
```

I get all the elements well parsed except the last column 'Códigos Isin'
and this is because there is a break on html code '. I do not know
what to do with, i have tried this part but still does not work:

```
lista_text = lista_text + [str(elements.string).replace('<br/>','')]
```

After that I take the list to a np.array an then to a dataframe to export it as .csv. That part is already done, I only have to fix that issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just that you need to be careful about what [`.string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) does - if there are multiple children elements, it would return `None` - as in the case with `<br>`:

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what
>   `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be `None`

Use `.get_text()` instead:

```
for elements in resto:
    lista_text = lista_text + [elements.get_text(strip=True)]
```